# Apache Spark: Broadcast join not workling for cached dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I join two dataframes as:

```
 val secondDf= sparkSession.read.parquet(inputPath)
 joinedDf = firstDf.join(secondDf, Seq("ID"), "left_outer")
```

Spark seems to do a broadcast join and no shuffelling is happening.

But as soon as I am caching the smaller Df:

```
 val secondDf= sparkSession.read.parquet(inputPath).cache()
 joinedDf = firstDf.join(secondDf, Seq("ID"), "left_outer")
```

Spark is shuffeling for the join so no broadcast join seems to happen.

My question is: Why is this happening? And how can I avoid the shuffeling when I am caching one dataframe?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
firstDf.join(broadcast(secondDf), Seq....)
```

Not sure why caching should make a difference, Spark is a bit unpredictable sometimes.

You could try writing `secondDf` to disk and reading it back in instead of caching, if it's small the overhead of doing this will be minimal.